# problems pinging a hyper-v VM

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, ping

On a Windows 2008R2 server, I am hosting another 2008R2 server VM using Hyper-V.  The server appears to be running fine.  From the host server, I can ping the VM:

```
Pinging SRV-ADTEST [fe80::c46c:e738:93a8:7a7%19] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::c46c:e738:93a8:7a7%19: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::c46c:e738:93a8:7a7%19: time=1ms
Reply from fe80::c46c:e738:93a8:7a7%19: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::c46c:e738:93a8:7a7%19: time<1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::c46c:e738:93a8:7a7%19:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms
```

From a Windows 7 laptop on the same network,  I try the same thing.  The first ping resolves the VM using IPv6 and gets a different address, and is unreachable.  The second time I try, it resolves to the IPv address and gets a reply.  I don't understand what's going on here.

Attempt #1:

```
Pinging SRV-ADTEST [fe80::c46c:e738:93a8:7a7%12] with 32 bytes of data:
Destination host unreachable.
Destination host unreachable.
Destination host unreachable.
Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for fe80::c46c:e738:93a8:7a7%12:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Attempt #2:

```
Pinging SRV-ADTEST [192.168.1.151] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.151: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.151: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.151: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.151: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.151:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 24ms, Average = 6ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily an answer, but I cannot post comments (yet).

1. Have you logged directly into the VM (SRV-ADTEST) and checked what IP Addresses it has registered and with what DNS Server?
2. Have you checked the DNS database to verify what is associated with SRV-ADTEST?

To me, it seems like SRV-ADTEST is registering two IPv6 addresses or registered the one your Windows 7 client is resolving from DNS while the actual one has now changed to the other one that you Hyper-V host is able to use because it is a Guest.

Harold